# Run an Azure Function Every 15 minutes

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function whose method looks like this:

```
[FunctionName("RunTask")]
public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */15 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
  log.Info("Running task...");
  await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

The above method is only a shell to test the timing abilities. I want the function to run every 15 minutes. However, the task seems to only run on the first pass. I'm basing this on what I see in the Azure Portal. In the Azure Portal, I select the `RunTask` function to view the Logs. This lets me watch the trace logs in real time.

The first log appears correctly. However, I do not see any additional logs written. Instead, I see "No new trace in the past [x] min(s)."

Oddly, if I change the timer from 15 minutes to 5 minutes (`[TimerTrigger("0 */15 * * * *")]` to `[TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]`), it works as expected. Why is that? How do I setup my function to run every 15 minutes?

Please note, I have to use the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.24 implementation.

Thank you!

Comment: have you created this function directly from portal or through Visual Studio?

Comment: I thought every 15 was different https://crontab.guru/every-15-minutes

Comment: Have a try of this: `59 14,29,44,59 * * * *`

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the timer trigger. Your function is triggered every 15 minutes successfully, but the log window is fragile. It sometimes will not show the logs after a few minutes, so when you set the timer from 15 to 5 minutes it shows the logs normally.

For this problem, you can see the logs of your function by following the steps below:

1. Go to "kudu" of your function app.
   [image]
2. Then click "Debug console" --> "CMD" --> "LogFiles" --> "Application" --> "Functions" --> "function", choose your function, click the edit pencil, then you can see the logs.
   [image]

Comment: I think there is a problem with the timer setting, I'm seeing the same issue